# ActivityRecognitionAPI throws IllegalStateException on some devices

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I've been testing the `ActivityRecognitionAPI` on two Android phones. Generally it works, but on some phones I'm getting an `IllegalStateException`.

Is this a problem with the phones themselves?

Phones tested:
Moto Z - OK
Samsung Galaxy J Ace - Not ok

I'm already making sure that the `GoogleApiClient` is connected.
And the exception is thrown in the 3rd line below:

```
Intent intent = Intent(app, ActivityRecognitionService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(app, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 0, pendingIntent)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html#requestActivityUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) say the API you're using is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I saw that but it says it might be deprecated in the future. Still I'll try using the newest API.